# Select Kendo UI grid row in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, protractor

I have an AngularJS web site with grid inside the main page, and I'm adding an auto-test project in Protractor.

I'm trying to click on the first row inside the grid:

```
this.firstResultInGrid = this.mainGrid.element(by.className('gridTextContent'));
this.firstResultInGrid.click();
```

but nothing happen.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The select method of the grid API? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-select